# Что значит данный кусок кода,нигде не могу найти информации!

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

Добрый день уважаемые пользователи,в общем задача была такая:
***Если все нечетные биты числа типа unsigned равняются единицам,вывести один,иначе ноль***

*Например:* битовое представление числа "10"="1010",все нечетные биты здесь-единицы **=>** ответ **1**.

Изначально дана функция,принимающая один параметр:

```
int any_odd(unsigned x) {
 //Ваш код.
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста,что делает данный кусок ***кода***:

```
int any_odd(unsigned x)
 {
  return x & 2863311530 ? 1 : 0;
 }
```

Также есть такой **вариант:**

```
int any_odd(unsigned x) {
  return (x & 0xAAAAAAAA) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Непонятны именно условия:

```
x & 2863311530
(x & 0xAAAAAAAA)
```

Заранее огромное спасибо!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ерунду он делает :)

Он, если установлен хоть один нечетный бит, возвращает 1, иначе 0.

2863311530 в бинарном виде равно 10101010101010101010101010101010

Дальше понятно: если установлен в 1 хоть один нечетный бит в числе `x`, значение `x&0xAAAAAAAA` будет ненулевым (он даст 1 в результат). Четные биты обнулятся.

Правильнее - если и в самом деле нужны **ВСЕ** нечетные биты - написать

```
rerturn x&0xAAAAAAAA == 0xAAAAAAAA;
```

Но это относится только к 32-разрядным числам. Если вы хотите игнорировать все нулевые биты перед первым единичным битом числа - т.е. чтобы, скажем, 101010 проходило проверку, а 100010 - нет, то тут немного сложнее. Простейший вариант - просто циклически выполнять сдвиги на 2 разряда вправо с проверкой установленности очередного нечетного бита.

Comment: Простите я не совсем понял некоторые моменты:1)Почему именно *2863311530*? 2)Что это вообще такое?? `x&0xAAAAAAAA`

Comment: Еще раз и медленно: *2863311530 в бинарном виде равно 10101010101010101010101010101010*. Или 0xAAAAAAAA в шестнадцатеричном. Число, у которого все нечетные биты равны 1, а четные - 0.

Comment: Понял,спасибо большое!Удачного вам дня.